# Suppose $n|m$. Prove that $n = gcd(m,n)$

Tags: proof-verification, gcd-and-lcm

We say $g ∈ N = gcd(a, b)$ if these are true:

$1.$ $g$ divides both $a$ and $b$.

$2.$ Whenever $d ∈ N$ divides $a$ and $b$, then $d$ also divides $g$.

($N$ is the set of natural numbers and $gcd$ is the greatest common denominator).

So, to show $n = gcd(m, n)$, I need to satisfy $1.$ and $2.$

$1.$ $n|m$ is given, and $n|n$ is true because $n$ can be expressed as $n = kn$ for $k = 1$.

$2.$ Suppose $d ∈ N$, and $d|m$ and $d|n$. Then $d|n$ is given.

Therefore $gcd(m, n) = n$ when $n|m$.

Is this a correct proof? I was unsure of it because so much was already given to me without much actual work having to be done.

Comment: Seems fine to me.  But make sure 2 is the definition you are given.  I've usually seen gcd defined as g = gcd(a,b) if i) g|a and g|b and ii) if d|a and d|b then $d \le g$.  It's an equivalent statement, but it requires me to show if d|n and d|m then d $\le$ n (which is obvious) instead.

Comment: ... assuming all variables are positive integers.